# What does underscore generic do in F#

Tags: generics, f#

Simple question. What does _ do in place of generic < >, so it looks like <_>?

Example code:

```
let errorEvent = Event<_>()
```

Another example:

```
let agent = new ClientAgent<_>(f)
```

What _ does? Does F# inferences type automatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

A simple example:

```
let list = new List<_>([1; 2; 3])
list |> Dump
```

The `list` local is inferred to be of type `List<int>`.

Comment: @KoBi in most cases you can also completely omit the type parameter braces: `let dict = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(); dict.Add(5,"five")`